# Ошибка адресации в 64-битном коде

Tags: отладка, x86-64, memory

Существует ли стандартный способ отловить ошибки преобразования указателей `(_int32)(void*) pointer`?

Может есть какой-нибудь способ заставить кучу выделять в адресном пространстве `> 0xFFFFFFFF`, чтобы потом отследить обращения по адресам `<= 0xFFFFFFFF`.

Или может зарезервировать это пространство с GUARD флагом? Уже замучался ловить такие ошибки в чужом коде.

Comment: grep не поможет ? Еще была такая утилитка - lint. Не знаю, как сейчас.

А вообще, вопрос интересный. ОС какая ?

Comment: ос пусть будет windows. например при переходе к x64 функция winapi (int somefunc) стала (INT_PTR somefunc). а некоторые личности это забывают.. и везде эти static cast'ы :(

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/assessing-and-sizing-intel-64-bit-architecture-porting/

Посмотрите, может пригодиться ?

Comment: я это все прекрасно знаю. интересует механизм поиска ошибок в чужом коде... попробую зарезервировать все доступные страницы до 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: есть платная приблуда viva64 (http://www.viva64.com/). Она как раз делает хитрый статический анализ и находит потенциальные проблемы. Но сильно дорогая.
Но как позитив - там на сайте очень много интересных статей на эту тему.

Comment: "попробую зарезервировать все доступные страницы до 0xFFFFFFFF" - Не понимаю, как у Вас что-то работать будет ?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.
Если вы используете Visual Studio, то начиная с 2003 версии была опция компилятора `/Wp64`, которая заставит компилятор выдавать предупреждение вида

```
warning C4311: 'type cast' : 
pointer truncation from 'void *' to 'int'.
```

при компиляции 32-битного приложения.
В более новых версиях предупреждение должно по идее выдаваться само при компиляции под 64 бит.